# @ResponseBody does not produce json with Hibernate Call

Tags: json, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have the `Controller` class which gets executred. But I don't get any response.

I am using `<mvc:annotation-driven />` and have `jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar` and `jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar` in `\WEB-INF\lib`.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/persons.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces={"application/json"})
public @ResponseBody Collection<Person> getPersons() {
    Collection<Person> persons = personService.findPersons("Smith"); // request comes here 
    System.out.println("persons " + persons); // This works fine
    // If I discard the result and add dummy data it works fine.
    return persons;
}
```

I get `500 Internal Server Error` in rest client. No exception stack trace in console appears.

Comment: Your method seems to be missing a return statement?!

Comment: What do you mean by "not getting a response"? Do you get an empty response, an error or does the HTTP call not return at all?

Comment: Then there ought to be a stack trace hidden somewhere. Check your logs and add it to your post.

Comment: what's your spring config?

Comment: @moxn question updated.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem may be in the `@RequestMapping` value as a `.htm` request. Because of the extension, Spring may set the media type to HTML rather than JSON. Therefore, you may want to change the request mapping to `value = "/persons.json"`

Secondly, your `produces = {"application/json"}` does not need to have the curly braces {}. It can be: `produces = "application/json"`

Also, does your Spring configuration have the Jackson mapper like the following:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SourceHttpMessageConverter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 6 you don't have to remember exactly what to configure `produces` to, just remember there is a class that has all the different media types predefined, look that class up, find the media of your choice and import it statically:

```
import static javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON;
```

so that you can write tidy code that's simply more readable:

```
@RequestMapping( ... produces=APPLICATION_JSON ... )
```

It's a quick win.

Here is the corresponding documentation:
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/MediaType.html